# vue.js select v-model value not in $(element).val()

Tags: drop-down-menu, vue.js, local-storage

I'm trying to load form values from a cache on route load so if someone navigates from one route to another they don't lose their settings. Checkboxes and text inputs are working correctly. Only selects seem to have an issue.

Here's the element:

```
<select id="client" name="client[]" multiple="" v-model="chosen_clients">
   <option v-for="client in clients" v-bind:client="client" :value="client.id">@{{ client.name }}</option>
</select>
```

First, I check the cache and update the address bar:

```
beforeCreate: function(){
    if(sessionStorage.getItem('invoiceable')){
        router.push({ path: '/invoiceable?'+sessionStorage.getItem('invoiceable')});
    }
},
```

Then I bind the data to the address bar:

```
data: function(){
    return {
        chosen_clients: this.$route.query['client[]'] ? (Array.isArray(this.$route.query['client[]']) ? this.$route.query['client[]'] : [this.$route.query['client[]']]) : [],
    }
},
```

Later, after mounted, I want to fetch data and update the address bar, but there's a problem:

```
var data = $('#invoiceable-form').serialize();
//This information does not match
console.log(this.chosen_clients); //This is correct
console.log($('#client').val(); //This is empty, even though visually, the select has selected options
```

Eventually, $('#client').val() has the correct value (meaning the visibly selected options appear as part of the serialized form. I know this because I have console.logs set up on beforeUpdate less than a second after the value is not present in .serialized it shows up without any interaction with the select. Even if I manually set $('#client').val([2,12]); before I .serialize() the correct values aren't there. I can force the issue by manually adding data to the result of .serialize, but that feels hacky.

Comment: You might just need to wait for [next tick](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick) for the DOM to be in sync with the data.

Comment: I would be totally down with that, except the options are selected! I'm going to throw an alert to confirm. I also want to say that all other input types are working correctly. I have checkboxes and text inputs that work correctly.

Comment: You're right. The select options weren't loaded yet. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Roy J was right. The select options weren't loaded yet.